# UIToolbar loses translucency in iOS7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

After running a build of our app on iOS7.1 we quickly noticed that several UIToolbars that we were using lost their 'glassy' translucent appearance and became totally transparent!

I have subclassed UIToolbar to make a custom view with some text on it.

I tried changing the translucency option and a few other properties of the UIToolbar but couldn't get the effect back?

How do I get the translucent appearance back?

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a while I found a few people battling this problem on some open source projects. I managed to gather that the problem is a UIToolbar must be a subview of another view - it seems you cannot subclass it directly any more.

So the solution was to make my custom view a subclass of UIView and do the following in `initWithFrame` (assuming a property, "toolbar" is added to the class):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self addSubview:self.toolbar];
        self.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        self.toolbar.translucent = YES;
        [...]
    }
return self;
}
```